# Cancel/Clear button event Post Back And Trying To Validate Fields

Tags: c#

this is driving me crazy.

I have a piece of code on a Windows Form Control, this code ensures the form clears and put the focus back to the first Control (Phone Number). The problem is I am using On-Leave Event Handles and this handler contain the Validation code so that the Phone is validated when the use leaves the control.

When I hit Reset or Exit of the form, it not only clears the form, it also sends the focus back to the Phone field, causing the control (Textbox) to Validate.

I need the focus on the Phone control with at the validation on focus, is there a way I can prevent this behavior?

```
private void txtPhone_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Int64 ConvertPhone;
            if (txtPhone.Text.Trim().Length != 10)
            {
                lblPhoneError.Visible = true;
                lblErrorIndicator.Visible = true;
                lblErrorIndicator.Text = "*Valid 10 digit phone number required";
            }

            else if (Int64.TryParse(txtPhone.Text, out ConvertPhone))
            {
                lblPhoneError.Visible = false;
                lblErrorIndicator.Visible = false;
                txtPhone.MaxLength = 10;
                txtPhone.Text = txtPhone.Text.Substring(0, 3) + "." + txtPhone.Text.Substring(3, 3) + "." + txtPhone.Text.Substring(6, 4);
           }

        }

 private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPhone.Clear();
        txtPhone.Focus();
    }


    private void txtPhone_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPhone.Text = txtPhone.Text.Replace(".", "");
    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: I am also using an Enter Handle (Event) for the phone formatting but I wanted to keep it brief here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (txtPhone.Text.Trim().Length != 10)
            {

```
            if (txtPhone.Text != "")
            {
                lblErrorIndicator.Visible = true;
                lblErrorIndicator.Text = "*Valid 10 digit phone number required";
            }
        }
```

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPhone.Clear();
        lblErrorIndicator.Text="";
        txtPhone.Focus();
    }

I can understand your problem but tell me what you want to do at the end?

Comment: At the end I simply need the focus to go back to the phone textbox but without triggering validation on the leave event in the phone textbox.
You solution fixes the issue but now I cannot get the phone number to format like this: 567.876.1234 as was in the original code.